# Generate a list of whole numbers uniformly at random with a given sum

Tags: python, random

I have seen several posts on this subject already, however they all seem unnecessarily complicated, or wrong --- the following proposal does not suffer from the former problem (it is simple), but possibly the latter (that it is wrong).

My goal is to generate `s` whole numbers, *i.e.*, positive integers, uniformly at random, such that their sum is `n`.  To me, the following solution of generating `n` random numbers between 1 and `s`, and then outputting the frequencies gets what we want:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

samples = list()

for i in range(n) :
    samples.append(random.randint(1,s))

hist = defaultdict(int)

for sample in samples :
    hist[sample] += 1

freq = list()

for j in range(s) :
    freq.append(hist[j+1])

print('list:', freq)
print('sum:', sum(freq))
```

So, for example, if we wanted s=10 random whole numbers which sum up to n=100, we would get from this procedure, for example

```
list: [11, 7, 9, 12, 16, 13, 9, 10, 8, 5]
sum: 100
```

Since I am no statistician by any means, I fear that this generates numbers which are not truly uniformly distributed.  Any comments/analysis would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If the code works but could just be improved, it should be on Code Review. This site is primarily for fixing broken code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "uniformly at random"? Should each individual number appear equally often, or should each valid combination be equally probable? In case of the first: Note that for, e.g., three numbers to sum to 5, if the first number is 1, the others can be (1,3), (2,2) or (3,1), but if the first is 3, the other two can only be (1,1), i.e. some constituting numbers can be used in more combinations any may (should?) thus appear more often.

Comment: About the un-uniformity in your sample: The random number generation works well enough, your sample is just too small. Try with `n=1000` or `n=10000`. If the numbers would appear equally often for any sample, they would not be random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what you present here is [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), I believe. Directly from wikipedia - "it models the probability of counts for rolling a s-sided die n times.", with
parameters vector p<sub>i</sub> = 1/s.

> however they all seem unnecessarily complicated, or wrong

not sure what you had in mind, but in Python world to sample from multinomial means you use NumPy and then it is one-liner

```
import numpy as np

result = np.random.multinomial(n, [1.0/s for _ in range(s)])
```

And likely it would be faster, well tested and correct for all possible combination of parameters.

If you find it is better suited you, so be it, but inventing new way to sample well-known distribution is quite a job in itself. Please note, that there a lot of distribution where sum of outcomes is equal to fixed number - f.e., [Dirichlet-multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution). And they have a lot of parameters which you could vary wildly, achieving statistically different results.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine *s* = 10 and *n* = 1_000_000. Then all the numbers would tend to cluster around 100_000. I'm pretty sure that what you actually have is a poisson distribution with lambda = *n*/*s*.

If you want something more like a uniform distribution, you can try something like this:

-Generate s random numbers between 0 and 1 and let *sum* denote their sum.

-Multiply each number by (n / *sum*), and let us name these decimal numbers *d*_1, …, *d*_s.

-Round down to the nearest integer and call the numbers i_1, ..., i_s.

Now, the sum of these is some *n*_i which may be less than *n* because of rounding. Let *rest* = *n* - *n_i*. Sort the i_1, …, i_s based on the rest of d_1, …, d_s with division by 1 (i.e. sort {i_1, …, i_s} based on the sorted sequence of {d_1 % 1, …, d_s % 1}) with lowest values at lowest indices. Then:

```
for j in range(rest):
    i_(s-j) += 1
```

This will give you s random numbers with identical uniform distributions which are scaled such that Sum(*i*_1, …, *i*_s) = *n*.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, he doesn't have a poisson distribution, please read my answer

Comment: Thank you, yes, the vector follows a multinomial distribution. I assumed from the title that he was interested in a uniform distribution for each variable, and since each entry in a multinomial distribution is independently poisson distributed with a scale factor applied to the vector of distributions, I thought this was an apt description.